# Move Slider until Value is reached

Tags: c#, wpf, while-loop, slider

I try to "animate" a slider while a certain value is true, until it reaches a designated value. But for some reason it does not work as easy as I thought:

```
while (depthScan == true)
{
    depth_max_slider.Value += 10;
    Console.WriteLine("Working");
    if (blobCount <= 400)
    {
        depth_max_slider.Value += 10;

    }
    else
    {
        depthScan = false;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Please provide information on what it's doing.

Comment: Basically the whole program freezes and runs the the script in the background (which is logic, since its a while-loop), not noticeable for the user. I want the slider to be animated so the user can see that something is happening.

Comment: Is blobCount ever being updated? Seems like your else will never fire, so your loop will never end.

Comment: Also, there doesn't appear to be anything here which would throttle the loop to make the slide visible to the user. This could potentially loop extremely fast, taking your slider past your expected max value very quickly.

Comment: Yes, blobCount is being updated. And yes the program works fast, but even if I either set the count to 4000 or the incremental to a very slow number like 0.1 the program will still run until its done - not showing any animation. I read about Threading, would that concept work here?

Comment: If you are running in response to a button click etc. then you are running on the UI thread, and the UI will not update until the thread finishes doing your loop and can "get back to rendering".

Comment: You could spin up a "BackgroundWorker" in response to the button click, and then report progress back to the UI thread and update the slider control from there.  The BackgroundWorker class has support for reporting progress in this manner.

Comment: Yes, I control the loop with a button. Seems like your solution sounds reasonable. Gonna look for Tutorials. Do you got a good reference for me?

Thanks so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
public class MyWindow : Window
    {
        void StartButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            // This method will run on the UI thread

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // start the thread

            // UI thread continues immediately

            // exit click event handler, UI thread goes back to WPF control so it can keep rendering...
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            // This method will run on the UI thread

            double depth_max = (double) e.UserState; // grab the value of depth_max passed over from background thread

            depth_max_slider.Value = depth_max; // update the slider with this value

            // exit ProgressChanged event handler, UI thread goes back to WPF control so it can keep rendering...
        }

        void worker_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
        {
            // This method will run on the background thread

            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            int percentComplete = 0;
            double depth_max;

            while( depthScan == true )
            {
                depth_max += 10; // NOTE: don't touch the slider control from the background thread, use a double instead!

                worker.ReportProgress( percentComplete, depth_max ); // pass depth_max as the 2nd param, "user state", will show up in ProgressChangedEventArgs in ProgressChanged handler

                Console.WriteLine( "Working" );
                if( blobCount <= 400 )
                {
                    depth_max += 10;

                    worker.ReportProgress( percentComplete, depth_max );

                }
                else
                {
                    depthScan = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```